# API Spring boot com Java e MySQL salva id UUID como binário no banco, porém eu preciso que salve como string

Tags: java, mysql, api, spring-boot, uuid

Estou tentando utilizar UUID junto com banco MySQL 8.0, Java e Spring Boot como o ID dos recursos que forem criados pela API. Porém o Id que era para ser gravado como VARCHAR está sendo gravado como binário no banco de dados.
Então sempre que vou usar algum endpoint que precisa do id, eu passo o UUID em forma de string, mas o banco não está achando, o Dto que ele retorna é com o UUID em formato de string.

Se eu troco o tipo do Id para Long, então funciona tudo.

Minha hipótese é que como o MySQL gravou em binário o UUID, qndo eu envio a String UUID ele não converte na hora de buscar e por isso ele diz que não achou. Abaixo um vídeo rápido ilustrando o problema.

https://youtu.be/0Im8hInghes

partes relevantes do código.

Id no model está assim

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private UUID id;
```

Exemplo de como ele está na controller no @GetMapping

```
 @GetMapping("/{id}")
        public ResponseEntity<Object> getOneParkingSpot(@PathVariable(value = "id") UUID id){
            Optional<ParkingSpotModel> parkingSpotModelOptional = parkingSpotService.findById(id);
            if (!parkingSpotModelOptional.isPresent()) {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("Parking Spot not found.");
            }
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(parkingSpotModelOptional.get());
        }
```

**EDIT 1:**

Descobri uma solução para o problema, o tipo da variavel que o spring estava setando é "BINARY(255)". troquei para "VARBINARY(36)" e começou a funcionar. Porém continua aparecendo como "blob" no banco de dados.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(columnDefinition = "varbinary(36)")
private UUID id;
```

colocando o @Column(columnDefinition = "varbinary(36)") no id fez funcionar tb.

**EDIT 2:**

Tentei setar a variavel do UUID no banco como VARCHAR(36), porém aí da SQLException

```
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xAC'\xFFg\x19@...' for column 'id' at row 1
```

Acho que pq o MySQL tenta salvar em binário e dá erro, pois o campo está como VARCHAR.

Answer (score -3):

Olá, como vai?

Entendo que, se você quer salvar como string, deveria salvar como VARCHAR(36) e não como VARBINARY.

VARBINARY é um tipo de dado binário e VARCHAR não. Utilizando VARCHAR você não teria problemas com comparação ao salvar no banco de dados e tentar recuperar esses registros.

Você pode ler mais sobre os tipos de dados [aqui](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/sql-reference/mysql-data-types.php)

Espero ter ajudado! :)

Comment: Obrigado pela Repostas Splett. Trocando para VARCHAR(36), acabo recebendo uma exception de que são incompativeis os tipos, pois o banco transforma o UUID em binário, aí na tabela está como String, a partir dai recebo a exception. Coloquei no post a linha da exception que recebo.

Answer (score -3):

Bom dia!
Passei pelo mesmo problema e consegui resolver desta forma:
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Type(type = "uuid-char")
@Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(36)")
private UUID id;

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).